# Animate view width

Tags: android

Is it possible to control the width animation for a view that has `wrap_content`? Right now I have a `TextView` with a barrier to its right side. I have another background `View` that aligns to this barrier. When the `TextView` changes text it just flashes to the new width but I want to animate the width with an animator where I can control the timing, interpolator etc. I know that I can set something like `animateLayoutChanges` but the effect is not customisable.

Comment: I am not sure, but you can use something like `ValueAnimator`.  Using the text length you can use the `ValueAnimator`, then it will give you each character index. You can use that to append character one by one to the `TextView` and hence the width will animate.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that but the problem is I won't know the end width until the view changes. I could add a ``onLayoutChangeListener`` and force the width to remain the old one and animate it myself but it feels kind of hacky.

Comment: viewObj.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // get view width and height
                }
            });

Comment: maybe this link will help you https://www.androidtutorialonline.com/animation-effects-to-text/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ObjectAnimator` along with `AnimatorSet` for the animation.

Here is an `extension` in `kotlin` for the `view` on which you want to apply the animation.

```
inline fun View.animateWidth(duration: Long = 1000, startDelay: Long = 0) {
    val scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleX", /*Change width*/)
    //val scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleY", /*Change width*/)
    val set = AnimatorSet()
    //set.playTogether(scaleX, scaleY)
    set.playTogether(scaleX)
    set.duration = duration
    set.startDelay = startDelay
    set.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    set.addAnimatorListener(
            onStart = { this.isClickable = false },
            onEnd = { this.isClickable = true }
    )
    set.start()
}
```

Comment: But I do not know the width. Let's say I'm changing the text from "blah" to "blahblahblah", how would I know what values to input?